# How to get access to MAMP mysqldata base when 1045 access denied error is posed?

Tags: macos, mysql, mamp

Been stuck for a few days now. I've been SCOURING google for solutions and have tried many things. Basically I was editing my users in phpMyadmin and I think I erased the user 'root' which is my access to my MAMP database? I am getting the #1045 access denied can not recognize password 'yes' or 'no' error....

[This article](http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/) I want to say is the closest I've found but still no dice. I have the newest version of MAMP PRO if that helps. Please let me know what other info you may need to help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have actually deleted the 'root' user, I would check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql) for MAMP.

Note that the #1045 Access Denied is a generic response that can apply to both a user that doesn't exist as well as simply using an incorrect password. So I would attempt to double-check that root really doesn't exist with a password reset attempt before forging on to replacing the root user account for MySQL.